# Sliding of onepage-scroll.js not works properly on tablet?

Tags: jquery, ios, fullpage.js

I am trying to use onepage-scroll.js.

i have problems scrolling in a tablet, iPad, while i am trying to view demo of jquery.onepage-scroll.js served locally on my mac. i can view this local page from iPad safari but the scroll just not sliding, suddenly switching usually skipping the next page; and not responding easily. 
also, some pages' text are not on the screen, and on each page i see scroll bar when i touch (thought may be related to the problem and illuminates parts.)

but it is ok when navigate by tapping pagination bullets.

i want this plug-in's one page scroll animation and pagination bullets at the same time.

What is the problem? How to fix it?

Another page by page scroll plug-in fullPage.js does have the pagination bullets and its scroll works on my iPad safari and on desktop browser.

Comment: I have the same issue. I think it might be to do with the way scroll is handled on the ipad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fullPage.js does have bullets if you use the option `navigation:true`.
Here's a living example:

http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/navigationV.html

You should initializate the plugin with the `navigation` option set to true:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.fn.fullpage({
        navigation: true,
        navigationPosition: 'right'
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks. when i added navigation options as you written above my whole page length sections has become one line height. Why? and couldn't get the bullets.

Comment: What do you mean? One pixel height? Can you give us a link to see it? Which errors does the javascript console shows?

Comment: Of course, you don't have to use the same options I posted, that's an example. The ones you have to add are `navigation` and `navigationPosition` if you want to place it on the left.

Comment: not one pixel one line height as if it is a div of which i did not specify height but put some text into it. i am running on local, sorry.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand you... You have the living example on the website I posted. Check it out and try to do it in the same way and you will have it working. I'm afraid I can not help you more without any link to your site or to a reproduction of your site/error in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). Good luck!

Comment: thanks. it works now. i have made syntax errors. now it is ok. and i could not think to put it to jsfiddle when u asked link, sorry :). by the way thai for the software, as well.

Comment: just one thing: i want to be able to implement such functionalities as in this example of full page scrolling, but i am not capable of javascript. should i go query way or prefer implementing myself in sans jquery, like it is done in [Efficient Mobile web librarY (EMY)](http://www.emy-library.org)

Comment: You don't have to implement anything. The scrolling example is done by just using the option `scrollOverflow: true`. You should take a look at [the documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#fullpagejs) to explore all the plugin possibilities and how to use them.

Comment: i know. i plan to use that plug-in now. what i meant about implementing was general about my programming skills and preferences to gain them.

Comment: You should accept the answer if it was valid for you. Other uses might ask the same.

Comment: i first marked answer as if it were the answer to my question.
my question was and is how to fix before mentioned misbehaviour of onepage-scroll.js plug-in in tablets. your answer has helped me and made trying to fix the problem mentioned unnecessary and made me leave other plug-in. but it is not the direct answer to my question. so i unaccepted the answer back. the reason i keep question undeleted to make people who may ask same know about a working alternative. and probably after sometime i will delete it.

Comment: @user97457 ok, fair enough :)